# Return parent::function in a function

Tags: php, function, class, oop, return-value

```
class Test extends Parent {
   $a = 1;

   public function changeVarA() {
       $a = 2;
       return parent::changeVarA();
   }

}
```

Can Anyone please explain what does `return parent::function();` it do ?

Thank you...! ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will call the function `changeVarA` in the parent class.

When a class extends another class, and both have the same function name, the `parent::` call forces the parent version of the function to be called and used. The return part of it will simply return whatever the parent function returns after it completes:

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
    echo "Hello Again!\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
    echo "Hello World\n";
    parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
?>
```

output:

```
Hello World
Hello Again!
```

The example is taken from [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) which you really should take a look at.

Comment: " really should take a look at. " I agree, and i will, this was urgent for me to understand functionality of `return parent::function();`, what you're saying, if i understood corectly is that it will echo class A and class B example ?

Comment: @AnteKo I have modified the answer so that you understand the input and output better.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understanding one major error in my script :)

Comment: I think you have mistake in the output it will be `Hello World` in first line.